# How can I take a screenshot using duncan3dc/dusk library?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I am using the `duncan3dc` module in laravel, Successfully importing text from the default example But I do not know how to take a screenshot,

I just installed this module using Composer.

```
$ composer requires duncan3dc/dusk.
```

Does it mean that everything needed for this module is automatically installed?

Or do I need something else to take a screenshot?

Below is my controller code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use duncan3dc\Laravel\Dusk;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function test()
    {
        $dusk = new Dusk;
        $dusk->visit("http://example.com");
        $dusk->screenshot("ddd");
        echo $dusk->element("h1")->getText() . "\n";
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get this error:

> file_put_contents (/tmp/ddd.png): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or  directory

I think there is no folder, so I get the error, where should I create the folder in the project folder?

Comment: hey try this  - http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html its easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/duncan3dc/dusk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#080---2018-05-08) from version `0.8.0` you can pass  fully qualified path to `screenshot` method. So doing this will work (you should see the file `ddd.png` created near the php file):

```
$dusk = new Dusk;
$dusk->visit("http://example.com");
$dusk->screenshot("./ddd.png");
echo $dusk->element("h1")->getText() . "\n";
```

You can also pass absolute path:

```
$dusk->screenshot("C:\windows\temp\ddd.png"); // if you are using windows
```

or

```
$dusk->screenshot("/tmp/ddd.png"); // if you are using macos/linux
```